# Connecting Spring Cloud Applications in Docker Container

Tags: spring, docker, spring-cloud

I am attempting to host a Spring Cloud application in Docker containers.The underlying exception is as follows:

```
search_1     | Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Invalid URL: config:8888
```

I understand the reason is because of the URL specified in my config server.

```
spring.application.name=inventory-client
#spring.cloud.config.uri=http://localhost:8888
spring.cloud.config.uri=config:8888
```

On my development machine, I am able to use localhost. However, based on a past question (relating to connecting to my database), I learned that localhost is not appropriate in containers. For my database, I was able to use the following:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
spring.jpa.show-sql=false
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://db:5432/leisurely_diversion
 #spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5000/leisurely_diversion    
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
```

but this obviously did not work as expected for the configuration server.

My docker-compose file:

```
# Use postgres/example user/password credentials
version: '3.2'

services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    ports:
      - 5000:5432
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: example
    volumes:
      - type: volume
        source: psql_data
        target: /var/lib/postgresql/data
    networks: 
      - app
    restart: always
  config:
    image: kellymarchewa/config_server
    networks:
      - app
    volumes:
      - /root/.ssh:/root/.ssh
    restart: always
  search:
    image: kellymarchewa/search_api
    networks:
      - app
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8082:8082
    depends_on:
      - db
      - config
      - inventory
  inventory:
    image: kellymarchewa/inventory_api
    depends_on:
        - db
        - config
    ports:
     - 8081:8081
    networks:
      - app
    restart: always
volumes:
  psql_data:
networks: 
  app:
```

Both services are running under the same user defined network; how I allow the services to find the configuration service?

Thanks.

Comment: `http://config:8888`

Comment: As @spencergibb mentioned, without the protocol theme. This is a invalid url only. You need to just use proper url

Comment: Yes, thanks. Such a silly oversight on my part. I could not fully test the application yet; however, it is not giving the same error at least (it is now a valid URL of course). Hopefully the apps can communicate with that URL.

Comment: While, that did eliminate the "invalid URL" error, the services still do not seem able to find each other.My client services are failing to start because they cannot locate information relating to the database driver (from application.properties) or information injected through `@Value` (located in search-client.properties). I can see the application.properties values (though not the values specific to each client) if I access the config server's endpoints, but the services do not seem able to access them. However, I am able to get it to work on my local machine. What else might I be missing?